# Click event on highchart axis

Tags: jquery, svg, highcharts, jquery-events

I want to be able to bind an event to the axes in high charts, so I can expose some options for them in the UI (axis interval, text formatting, gridlines, etc.)

Doesn't seem to be a way to do this in highcharts.  So far, I can get it to do my bidding  when I click on the labels, but not when I click on the spaces between the labels.  See the fiddle here, for version 2.2.4: http://jsfiddle.net/gW4p6/174/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        marginRight: 80 // like left
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: [{
          lineWidth: 1,
          title: {
              text: 'Secondary Axis'
          }
    }],

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
});

var clearSelection = function() { $('.highcharts-axis').css('stroke', ''); };

$('.highcharts-axis').click(function(event) {
    clearSelection();
    $(this).css('stroke', 'green');
    return false;
});
$(document).click(clearSelection);
$('svg').click(clearSelection);
```

Is there any way that I can reliable catch a click event on the g.highcharts-axis element?

For bonus marks, what's the best way to link the axis with its axis.id in the options? Best I can come up with is to rely on the fact that axis are rendered in the order they are supplied, so I can just loop.

Comment: I worked on this for a few minutes yesterday.  I thought it had something to do with the pointer-event property (http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty).  The svg g element is not a "painted" element so the click events are based to it's children.  I attempted to set the property to "all" but that did not work either.  Damn, this is tricky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.highcharts-axis text').click(function(){ alert($(this).text());  });
```

This alerts the text of the axis. This way you could bind click event to each elements in axis.

Comment: I already had a similar solution - did you see the fiddle? I want to be able to click the spaces between the labels.

Comment: Does anyone know if this solution is still valid? The jsFiddle in the original question doesn't seem to work anymore, and I can't get the accepted solution to work on my machine--the event doesn't seem to bind at all, as if there is no class '.highcharts-axis text'... Thanks!

Comment: The solution was for highcharts v2.2.4, they seem to have changed their DOM structure for v3. I updated the fiddle to use 2.2.4 for funsies.

Comment: `$('.highcharts-axis-labels text').click(function(){ alert($(this).text());  });`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the click event. Take a look at the API:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.events.click

From the event handler you can get the string with "this.name"
or even get some kind of identifier with "this.options.somevariable"

"somevariable" means whatever variable name you create in the series data. For example in my case I name the identifier as simply "id":

```
{
   name: "My label",
   id: 6,
   events: { 
      click: function()
      {
         alert(
            'The name is ' + this.name +
            ' and the identifier is ' + this.options.id
         );
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The question is about the axis, not the series or the data point.